# Изображение на заднем фоне

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как сделать данный орнамент на заднем фоне при этом прижать его к правому и левому краёв? Пробовал сделать позиционированием, но не вышло. Подскажите, может быть у вас есть ответ на данный вопрос.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задайте два фоновых изображения для одного элемента через запятую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```css
body {
    background: #f2f0e3; /* Цвет фона веб-страницы */ 
   }
   .block {
    background: url(http://htmlbook.ru/example/images/bg_left.gif) repeat-y,
                #fff url(http://htmlbook.ru/example/images/bg_right.gif) repeat-y 100% 0; 
    padding: 10px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
   }
```

```html
<div class="block">
   За 11 месяцев вахты радисты провели 8642 сеансов связи общим 
   объемом 300625 групп. Это только метео и аэротелеграммы. 
   Принято от радиостанции мыс Челюскин 7450 групп.
</div>
```

[Ресурс](http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-dobavit-dva-fona-k-odnomu-elementu-cherez-css3)